# jQuery get(): How to show topics looping through results

Tags: jquery

`.get()` returns two models first chapters and second is topics.
I am getting the chapters using `for` loop perfectly but, I want to show topics against each chapter if available. Where each topic have value of chapterid.

This is my code:

```
$.get("/Ajax/ChaptersListBySubjectID", {
            SubjectID
        }, function(data) {
            if (data != null) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.ChaptersList.length; i++) {
                    ChaptersData += "<li class='list-inline-item col-lg-5 col-md-5 chpli'>" +
                        "<a id=" + data.ChaptersList[i].ChapterID + " onclick='checkthis(this)'>" +
                        "<h5>" + data.ChaptersList[i].ChapterName + "</h5>" +
                        "</a>" + "<span class='fa fa-chevron-down'>" + "<span>" +
                        "</li>";

                }
                ChaptersData += "</br>" + "</br>" + "<a onclick='return validateChapter()' id='allSelectedValues' href=# class='AddQBtn btn btn-primary' > NEXT <span class='fa fa-chevron-right'></span> </a>";
            }
```

I expected show topics against each chapter if available using jquery.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide example for your `data` object.

Comment: Provide same data and expected results and a more detailed problem description. Hard to guess what problem is when it isn't explained

Comment: Dear brother thanks for reply. My question is that i am fetching two models objects (chapters and topics) using get method. and i want to show all those topics where chapter id is matched with topics table.

Comment: Still needing what Charlietfl said... there's no way we can help without you providing that, even with your explanation (that must be included in the question in an [edit], not in the comments)